# Getting E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to POST request for '/svn/repo/!svn/me'

Tags: linux, svn, commit

Having this error when ever i try to commit the updated file.
I have looked in the authz file and checked error log, but I am not getting a good answer from those
Dont know why, anyone able to help!?

Comment: To me this looks like a question for the subversion mailing list; also note that there's heaps of similar reports out there, some of which have working resolutions.

Comment: What do you see in the server logs?

Answer (score -1):

This is what i see in the error_log:

[Thu Jun 20 19:06:15.104386 2019] [:error] [pid 1069] [client 172.29.6.128:43724                                                                                                                                                             ] could not begin a transaction  [500, #13]
[Thu Jun 20 19:06:15.104405 2019] [:error] [pid 1069] [client 172.29.6.128:43724                                                                                                                                                             ] Can't open file '/var/www/svn/repo/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied  [5                                                                                                                                                             00, #13]

So initailly, i did svn co "url of repo"
edited a txt file
then i tried to svn ci -m "edited txt file"

but it throws that 500 error

svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to POST request for '/svn/repo/!svn/me'

and the log file shows the above message. That file that says permission denied, is owned by root user and thats what im logged in as